# Add column to laravel user model and keep the auth register behavior

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

As many know, Laravel automatically creates the User model when you create a project. I then created an auth interface `php artisan make:auth`. The auto generated register method was working normaly. I then added a not null column to the migration for the user table. Now it isn't working anymore. I don't know where exactly the insert happens when laravel creates this auth scaffolding. I tried editing the `create` method in `RegisterController` but it didn't worked.

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'tipo' => $data['tipo'], // name of the new column I added
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

On the register `<form>` I added the input field `tipo`. The generated code includes:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">

<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

<select id="tipo" class="form-control" name="tipo" value="{{ old('tipo') }}" required>
                                <option value="1">Gerente</option>
                                <option value="2">Caixa</option>
                                <option value="3">Garçom</option>
</select>

<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

<input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Registrar
</button>
```

In the User class model, I added the new column to the fillable:

```
/protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'tipo',
];
```

On the routes, web.php only `Auth::routes();`. If I run `php artisan route:list` it shows me that for the `POST` method the uri `register` leads to `RegisterController@register` but on the RegisterController it has only the create method I posted and validator method. So, where the registration is actually happening? In terms of laravel, where it runs the `$user->save()` method?

**Edit:** All I want to do is modify it so it include the new `<input>` for the new column

**Edit 2:** I found out that actually the code is not reaching the `create` method because I added  `dd($data)` before the return and still the same behavior, then I added some forced syntax error and also the same thing happened.

Comment: Can you please post the form code and the output of the posetd $data array from inside your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Add the recently added column to $fillable array in the app\User.php file.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'tipo'
    ];
```

Comment: Before return of create method on RegisterController, add `dd($data);` then share output.

Comment: It's on trait RegistersUsers on path `[project-root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I put the wrong output because I was in another folder lol, the result of `route:list` is actually  sanduicheIche\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register